# How to get the raw query from EntityRepository from the controller

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, doctrine-query

I need to get the raw query as a string, something like this.

> $query = 'SELECT p FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p WHERE p.upvotes >
>   x ORDER BY p.createdAt ASC';

My custom "findAllNewestByVotes" method contains the query.

```
class ImageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllNewestByVotes($maxvotes)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT p FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p WHERE p.upvotes > '.$maxvotes.' ORDER BY p.createdAt ASC')
        ->getResult();
    }

}
/**
 * @Route("/world/front",name="world-front")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction()
{
    $images = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('GabrielUploadBundle:Image')->findAllNewestByVotes(50);

    ladybug_dump($images);
    return $this->render('GabrielLayoutBundle:Worldpage:index.html.twig',array('images'=>$images));
}
```

What I need is something like 
$images->getRawQuery() // returns query as a string

---

Solution (reference to best answer)

```
    /**
     * ImageRepository
     *
     * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
     * repository methods below.
     */
    class ImageRepository extends EntityRepository
    {
        public function findAllNewestByVotes($maxvotes)
        {
            return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT p FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p WHERE p.upvotes > '.$maxvotes.' ORDER BY p.createdAt ASC');
        } 
    }

> create image repository

    $images = $this->get('doctrine')->getRepository('GabrielUploadBundle:Image')->findAllNewestByVotes(50);
```

> ```
>  return the raw query as string like this
> ```

```
    $images->getDQL()
```

> ```
>  return objects like this
> ```

```
    $images->getResult();
```

Comment: The query as a string is pretty useless unless you're thinking about appending to it as a string which is ugly since Doctrine has so much easy to use functionality on dynamically building SQL queries.

Comment: if it was useless they wouldn't have created the getDQL() method 
(see answer)

Comment: It's useless for you and me -- the beneficiary/user of the library -- it is useful for lower level work.

Comment: Maybe for you, but I need to pass the getDQL() method to a bundle im using for pagination

Comment: That's a lower level integration. It's pretty stupid that the 3rd party bundle needs the DQL... why would it need a string if they could use the object directly and they could obtain the string from the object themselves?

Comment: Another example of lower level integration: without getSQL you can't actually run the SQL queries against the database back-end (ex.: MySQL) because MySQLi / PDO take strings as parameters. Doctrine does this under the covers in `getResult` it fetches the SQL string and uses MySQLi / PDO to communicate with the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The raw query can be retrieved using:

```
$this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT p
            FROM GabrielUploadBundle:Image p
            WHERE p.upvotes > '.$maxvotes.'
            ORDER BY p.createdAt ASC
    ')
    ->getSQL();
```

But this is a simple query, why not use DQL and add the parameters separately (using prepared statements which are safe from SQL inject attacks)?

```
$this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQueryBuilder()

    ->select('p')
    ->from('GabrielUploadBundle:Image')

    ->where('p.upvotes > :maxvotes')
    ->setParameter('maxvotes', $maxvotes)

    ->orderBy('p.createdAt', 'ASC')

    ->getSQL();
```

To be able to get the query (object) or query builder (object) from the controller you need to break the repository logic into 2 functions, one which builds the query and another which calls the query with parameters:

```
class ImageRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllNewestByVotesQuery($maxvotes)
    {
        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()

            ->select('p')
            ->from('GabrielUploadBundle:Image')

            ->where('p.upvotes > :maxvotes')
            ->setParameter('maxvotes', $maxvotes)

            ->orderBy('p.createdAt', 'ASC');
    }

    public function findAllNewestByVotes($maxvotes)
    {
        return $this
            ->findAllNewestByVotesQuery($maxvotes)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to get it from the controller without having to retype the string for every controller? in this case like $image->getSQL() or something?

Comment: Break it into two functions -- one builds the query and one calls it. You should be doing this in every repository you have so you can easily alter a query without having to copy-paste code.

Comment: sir since the second function throws an exception trying to call itself, I wouldn't qualify it as a working answer however I see how your answer was helpful so just accept the edit and were done

Comment: I didn't see an edit request -- if I had I would have accepted it. Or if you would have pointed the comment out to me in a comment etc..

Comment: I am reviewing the edit request but it's replacing my answer with yours entirely. when the problem is the function name typo which causes endless recursion.

Comment: I corrected the function name to call the query builder function.

Comment: it seems like if you're using `createQueryBuilder()` you'll have to chain first with `$query->getQuery()->getSql()`